# Need help in making SQL query

Tags: sql

i'm very new to SQL and don't know what is wrong with my query. plz guide

I have 2 tables product and product_consumer 1 to m relation.
i want to get all products and count of consumers of each product.

This is what i want:

```
id:    pCount
item1, 2
item2, 1
```

i have tried the following query but it only return 1st record/1 row only.

```
SELECT prd.*, COUNT(pc.id) pCount 
FROM `product` AS prd 
JOIN product_consumer pc ON pc.id = prd.id
```

Comment: At the end you just need to add 'GROUP BY id' to collect the results for each id

Comment: @JoeT Thanks, no wonder i was confused, i didn't learned GROUP BY clause. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT pc.id, COUNT(pc.id) pCount 
FROM product AS prd 
JOIN product_consumer pc ON pc.id = prd.id 
GROUP BY pc.id
```

Let's say your schema is this:

```
CREATE TABLE product(
  id int,
  product  varchar(1)
)

CREATE TABLE product_consumer(
  id int,
  consumer  varchar(1),
  pid int
)
```

if you want the details of all `products` with the `count` you need to include all the attributes of prd in `group by clause` like this :

```
SELECT prd.id, prd.product, count(pc.pid) as pCount  
FROM product AS prd 
JOIN product_consumer pc ON pc.pid = prd.id 
GROUP BY prd.id, prd.product, pc.pid;
```

Refer this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efd21/1)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, u saved me. hehe i'm still not sure how this works, can u explain plz what out my query generates, and how group by did the trick?

Comment: Your original query returns the total number of rows, while `group by` tells it to group them by product id and then count the no. of products in each group.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) Clause

```
SELECT prd.id, count(pc.id) pCount 
FROM product AS prd JOIN product_consumer pc ON pc.id = prd.id
GROUP BY prd.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you do not need the product name you do not need to join

```
SELECT id, count(*)
FROM product_consumer
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: actually i need all the details of product, thats why i used prd.*, for less typing i made the output little in example table, but your suggestion is informative, thanks